# Returning a specific element from an ArrayList but getting type mismatch error?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm currently in my second semester learning Java and for this project we're supposed to be using ArrayLists, enhanced for-each loops and linear search together. For the project I'm creating a task manager and with this method I want to be able to search the ArrayList for dates and then return the entire task with the correct date. I'm getting this error from the highlighted line below "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Task to ArrayList" Due to the assignments guidelines this method has to return it as an ArrayList, what am I doing wrong? and how can I fix it?

```
public ArrayList<Task> findTasksByDate(Date date) {
            while(i<taskMan.size()); {
            for (Task element: taskMan) {
                if (date.equals(taskMan.get(i).getDueDate())) {  
                return taskMan.get(i);//error with this line
                }
                return null;
            }
            i++;
        }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to return a single `Task` while the method defines you'll return a `ArrayList<Task>`. You probably want to store them in an intermediate list inside your method and then return that list at the end.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel How exactly should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return an ArrayList, you'll need to declare a local ArrayList, add the element to the list, then return the list. Like this:

```
public ArrayList<Task> findTasksByDate(Date date) {
            ArrayList<Task> returnList = new ArrayList<Task>();
            while(i<taskMan.size()); {
            for (Task element: taskMan) {
                if (date.equals(taskMan.get(i).getDueDate())) {  
                   returnList.add(taskMan.get(i));
                return returnList;
                }
                return null;
            }
            i++;
        }
}
```

Comment: I may not have phrased it well but I can't change the return type to Task it has to be an ArrayList due to the assignment guidelines. I need to be able to return task(s) that have matching dates to whatever the user entered.

Answer (score 0):

Your method declaration:

```
public ArrayList<Task> findTasksByDate(Date date) {
```

You're returning a `Task`, not an `ArrayList` of `Task`s.

Change it to:

```
public Task findTasksByDate(Date date) {
```

Comment: Like i said above due to the assignment guidelines this method has to return as an ArrayList not as a Task.

Answer (score -1):

Your method is returning ArrayList but you want to return a Task. So an Element of the Array.

Your Method should return Task insted of ArrayList

or

Create a new ArrayList and add the return Item to this new list.

```
public ArrayList<Task> findTasksByDate(Date date) {

            while(i<taskMan.size()); {
            for (Task element: taskMan) {
                if (date.equals(taskMan.get(i).getDueDate())) {  
                ArrayList<Task> returnList = new ArrayList<>(); // create new list.
                returnList.add(taskMan.get(i));//add
                return returnList; // return the new collection
                }
                return null;
            }
            i++;
        }
}
```

Comment: Like i said above due to the assignment guidelines this method has to return as an ArrayList not as a Task.

Comment: Instantiate a new array list. Add the task to this empty list. return the list.